# Xamarin View - How to put TextButton at the end and to the foreground

Tags: java, xml, google-maps, xaml, xamarin

I am trying to figure out. How I can put the Login-Button at the end of the view, but on the foreground of placeholderText. This green textfield should be replaced by a maps-view later.
My current code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            x:Class="FreemomentApp.GUI.Views.Examples.MapInterface"
            Shell.NavBarIsVisible="True">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="DarkOrange" >
            <StackLayout Padding="10,10,10,10" VerticalOptions="End" BackgroundColor="Aqua">
                <Label Text="placeholderText"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Padding="10,10,10,10" VerticalOptions="End">
                <Button VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Login"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

and my current state looks like this:

[image]

My targetview should looks like this:

[image]

It would be great, if somebody could help me with a hint. How I can reach my should state.

I wish you a good night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
             HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Aqua">
            
        <Label Text="placeholderText" Margin="10,10,10,10" />        
        <StackLayout Padding="10, 10, 10, 10" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
            <Button VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Login" />
        </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks this works!

For others you need to write "EndAndExpand" instead of EndandExpand".