# Xamarin View - How to put TextButton to the foreground of google map

Tags: c#, xml, google-maps, xaml, xamarin

I want to put my text button "login" to the foreground and into the google maps view. The aqua color should not be visible.

This question is related to [Xamarin View - How to put TextButton at the end and to the foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71190572/xamarin-view-how-to-put-textbutton-at-the-end-and-to-the-foreground), but actually does not solve my problem with google maps.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="StandApp.Views.MainMapPage"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps"
             Title="MapsPage1">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
             HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Aqua">

            <maps:Map x:Name="map" MyLocationEnabled="True" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <StackLayout Padding="10, 10, 10, 10">
                <Button VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Login" />
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

My current state looks like this:

[image: Current state]

Answer (score 0):

use a `Grid` with two rows.   Make the `Map` span both rows, then add the `Button` to only the 2nd row, on top of the map

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="80*,20*">
  <Map Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" ... />
  <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ... />
</Grid>
```